# Java HBase Program configuration

Tags: java, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am writing a Java program to write the output into the HBase. I have a question about how to configure the Hbase in my driver class. Now I configure like this:

```
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum.", "localhost");
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2222");
```

But if I am using the HBase cluster and all my RegionServers start the zookeeper, how can I configure this? Like this??

```
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum.", "RegionServer1");
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum.", "RegionServer2");
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum.", "RegionServer3");
...
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2222");
```

Is it correct?

Comment: Why all the RSs are starting a ZK??

Comment: I just set up the HBase based on the instructions in the Internet, which I add all the namenodes and datanodes into base.zookeeper.quorum in hbase-site.xml, is it not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `hbase.zookeeper.quorum` should be like this

```
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum","RegionServer1,RegionServer2,RegionServer3");
```

usually we define it in the xml file `hbase-site.xml`

Comment: Actually I have defined it in the base-stie.xml. So do you mean that I don't need to set it like above if I have defined it in base-site.xml?

Comment: Yes you don't need to set it if you have already defined it in hbase-site.xml